# How to get the information like the output of Model.get_config() in keras?

Tags: pytorch

I want to get some information like this.
The input layer of one layer and the output layer of one layer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with summary, here is an example

```
from torchsummary import summary

vgg = models.vgg16()
summary(vgg, (3, 224, 224))

----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shpae         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1         [-1, 64, 224, 224]            1792
              ReLU-2         [-1, 64, 224, 224]               0
            Conv2d-3         [-1, 64, 224, 224]           36928
              ReLU-4         [-1, 64, 224, 224]               0
         MaxPool2d-5         [-1, 64, 112, 112]               0
            Conv2d-6        [-1, 128, 112, 112]           73856
              ReLU-7        [-1, 128, 112, 112]               0
            Conv2d-8        [-1, 128, 112, 112]          147584
              ReLU-9        [-1, 128, 112, 112]               0
        MaxPool2d-10          [-1, 128, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-11          [-1, 256, 56, 56]          295168
             ReLU-12          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-13          [-1, 256, 56, 56]          590080
             ReLU-14          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
           Conv2d-15          [-1, 256, 56, 56]          590080
             ReLU-16          [-1, 256, 56, 56]               0
        MaxPool2d-17          [-1, 256, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-18          [-1, 512, 28, 28]         1180160
             ReLU-19          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-20          [-1, 512, 28, 28]         2359808
             ReLU-21          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
           Conv2d-22          [-1, 512, 28, 28]         2359808
             ReLU-23          [-1, 512, 28, 28]               0
        MaxPool2d-24          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-25          [-1, 512, 14, 14]         2359808
             ReLU-26          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-27          [-1, 512, 14, 14]         2359808
             ReLU-28          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
           Conv2d-29          [-1, 512, 14, 14]         2359808
             ReLU-30          [-1, 512, 14, 14]               0
        MaxPool2d-31            [-1, 512, 7, 7]               0
           Linear-32                 [-1, 4096]       102764544
             ReLU-33                 [-1, 4096]               0
          Dropout-34                 [-1, 4096]               0
           Linear-35                 [-1, 4096]        16781312
             ReLU-36                 [-1, 4096]               0
          Dropout-37                 [-1, 4096]               0
           Linear-38                 [-1, 1000]         4097000
================================================================
Total params: 138357544
Trainable params: 138357544
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
```